# class, BOOST_TEST_MODULE, BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE: problems from naming?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-unit-test-framework

So, I have started using boost unit testing. 
When I try and build a simple test that creates an instance of a class I get a compilation error.It works fine without an instance of the class.

The compilation error message is:

```
/src/test/WTFomgFail_test.cpp: In member function ‘void WTFomgFail::defaultConstructor::test_method()’:
/src/test/WTFomgFail_test.cpp:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘obj’
/src/test/WTFomgFail_test.cpp:20: error: expected `;' before ‘obj’
```

### WTFomgFail_test.cpp:

```
#include "WTFomgFail.hpp"

#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE WTFomgFail
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(WTFomgFail)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( defaultConstructor )
{
    WTFomgFail obj = WTFomgFail();
    BOOST_MESSAGE("wow, you did it");
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

### WTFomgFail.hpp:

```
#ifndef WTFOMGFAIL_HPP_
#define WTFOMGFAIL_HPP_

class WTFomgFail
{
public:
    WTFomgFail();
    ~WTFomgFail();
};

#endif /* WTFOMGFAIL_HPP_ */
```

### WTFomgFail.cpp:

```
#include "WTFomgFail.hpp"

WTFomgFail::WTFomgFail()
{
}

WTFomgFail::~WTFomgFail()
{
}
```

The error goes away if I change `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(WTFomgFail)` to something else, say `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(OMGreally)`.

Furthermore, I dont get the error when using `#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE OMGreally` with `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(OMGreally)`.

So, my question is when using the boost UTF is naming the module,  test_suite, and class the same thing explicitly forbidden?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know I'm late to this question, but I just stumbled across it and it looked so lonely...

To understand this restriction, you have to understand how Boost Tests *originally* worked. (It still can work this way, but back then there were no `BOOST_AUTO_...` macros and you *had* to do it this way.)

From the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-organization/manual-nullary-test-case.html):

```
class test_class {
public:
    void test_method1()
    {
        BOOST_CHECK( true /* test assertion */ );
    }
    void test_method2()
    {
        BOOST_CHECK( false /* test assertion */ );
    }
};

//____________________________________________________________________________//

test_suite*
init_unit_test_suite( int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{
    boost::shared_ptr<test_class> tester( new test_class );

    framework::master_test_suite().
        add( BOOST_TEST_CASE( boost::bind( &test_class::test_method1, tester )));
    framework::master_test_suite().
        add( BOOST_TEST_CASE( boost::bind( &test_class::test_method2, tester )));
    return 0;
}
```

This was a bit cumbersome, because every time you add a test function, you had to change code in two seperate locations (the definition of the function and the registering with the test suite). The registering is also somewhat non-intuitive.

That is why they introduced the `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE` and `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE`, which are doing this for you.

The parameter you pass to `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE` is, of course, the name of the class (`test_class` above). The parameter to `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE` is the name of the test function (`test_method1()` and `test_method2()` above).

So no, those may (of course) not be identical to the class and functions you are testing. You can use namespaces for this, but personally I prefer simply suffixing the class name with `Tu` (or `_tu` if you aren't into CamelCase naming), and using that for the test suite.

I hope this helps.